# multi location updates security rules in firestore

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

how can I ensure atomic writes of multiple document writes on client side only?
for example, when creating a record, a record document is generated and concurrently, a record log document is also generated (two different locations).

I wouldn't want the user to override by creating only the record document without the record log document. is this possible with the current firestore security rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `getAfter()` function to look at what the state of a document would be after a write or set of writes. You can use this to make sure a value in another document is updated, for example:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {

    // Allow a user to update a record or log only if they keep the timestamps equal for the same ID
    match /records/{record} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                      getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/logs/$(record)).data.timestamp == request.resource.data.timestamp;
    }

    match /logs/{log} {
      allow write: if request.auth.uid != null &&
                      getAfter(/databases/$(database)/documents/records/$(log)).data.timestamp == request.resource.data.timestamp;
    }
}
```

Docs: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.html#.getAfter

Comment: Docs are here now: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.firestore.html#.getAfter